# How can I programmatically show the toolTip on a TextInput when a validator returns "invalid"?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tooltip, validation, textinput

I have a form with a TextInput that has a custom Validator. I call the Validator logic and handle the result programmatically. This all works fine, except for one problem. The TextInput gets highlighted when it is invalid, but the toolTip that contains the errorMsg does not display until I roll the mouse cursor over the TextInput. Is there anyway to get the toolTip to show programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to programmatically re-create the text of the tooltip using the [ToolTipManager.createToolTip](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/ToolTipManager.html#createToolTip%28%29) function in your validator result handling function.

Check the documentation at the link, it seems pretty straightforward to spawn an instant tooltip.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to not have to go that far. To me, it should be much simpler than that - the ToolTip already exists, it's just not being displayed. I don't need to recreate an existing item, just show the one that's already created.

Comment: I think that may be your only option.  I imagine that behind the scenes, when you set the toolTip property in MXML, it's silently registering mouserOver and mouserOut event listeners for that UIComponent, then retrieving that stored toolTip string value from the UIComponent and calling createTooltip and destroyTooltip in the event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

You may have a look at:
[Better form validation in Flex](http://aralbalkan.com/1125)

This may help you to customize the validator .